# Efeito fade de elementos apenas ao vizualizá-los com bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

Gostaria de saber como fazer aquele efeito `fade` de elementos na página apenas quando ele é visualizado.
Por exemplo, tenho visto alguns sites feitos com `bootstrap` que ao ir rolando a página os elementos vão sendo mostrados com efeito `fade`, `fadeInUp`, `fadeInLeft`, etc.

Um exemplo para demonstrar seria esse [Site](http://seattle-bootstrap3-website-template.little-neko.com/v1/)

Após serem visualizados os efeitos já não ocorrem mais a não ser se a página for recarregada.

Alguém sabe como se faz isso utilizando o `css` do `bootstrap`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Isso é um efeito chamado Paralax, que é aonde vc define (a grosso modo) camadas e que velocidade cada camada de movimentará baseado no mouse, no scroll da pagina ou mesmo numa animação. Esse efeito é muito antigo e pode ser observado em jogos como Super Mario e etc.

Aqui tem um exemplo fantástico de site em Paralax bem avançado, no caso desses sites de bootstrap o efeito é aplicado apenas em algumas coisinhas bem leves.

[Site Fantástico com Paralax](http://boy-coy.com/)

[Site da Mozilla com esse efeito](http://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/os/)

Para se fazer esse efeito o mais normal é usar jQuery, e como tudo em jQuery existe um plugin pronto pra ser usado, eis alguns:

[Um Plugin jQuery](http://stephband.info/jparallax/)

[Um tutorial Legal](http://tableless.com.br/parallax-simples-com-jquery-e-css/)

[Um outro Plugin JQuery](http://ianlunn.co.uk/plugins/jquery-parallax/)

Procure entender como funciona e você poderá fazer o que quiser com esse efeito, desde pequenos detalhes em imagens ou até mesmo sites bitolados como esse que passei.

Espero ter ajudado,
Bons estudos.

Answer (score 1):

Você tem algum site que gostaria de copiar esse fade, fica melhor para explicar, mas aqui vai alguns links que podem te ajudar:

[mycodezone](http://www.mycodezone.com/bootstrap-carousel-with-fade-in-fade-out-effects/)

[bootply](http://www.bootply.com/XLxjrOn4zP) - Inclusive [aqui no bootply](http://www.bootply.com/tagged/fade)  tem vários snippets do bootstrap pra mim já foram muito úteis!

Valeuu!! :D

Comment: Esse site tem um exemplo:
http://seattle-bootstrap3-website-template.little-neko.com/v1/